# How can I code simultaneously with a friend on Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfsbuild

Is there an addon or extension for **Visual Studio** that will enable me to code C# programs with a fellow programmer **simultaneously**? Simultaneous as in my friend *sees what I am typing, as I am typing it*.

Comment: Two chairs in front of one computer works well.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600/can-you-pair-program-remotely

Comment: @BenVoigt Chairs? Its the 21st century - I say go with the Vulcan Mind Meld for sure. Its important to use the best tools available for the task you want done.

Comment: Of course, you should take a look to VS Anywhere! http://youtu.be/XQQih5zFb6E?hd=1 and www.vsanywhere.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tool you are looking for is VS Anywhere.

Here you can see [a video on YouTube](http://youtu.be/XQQih5zFb6E?hd=1). You can download from [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/99466148-ae68-4bd5-b66b-08bae7423a03), and you can look for more information on the [VS Anywhere web page](http://www.vsanywhere.com).

(I'm the VS Anywhere owner.)

Comment: I am a VS Anywhere user, and I have to say I love it for paired sessions.

Comment: Since VS Anywhere just became paid-only (I really liked it but it's a shame they went pay-only) and I can't afford a paid subscription, is there a free alternative I can find that allows simultaneous editing of code?

Comment: VS Anywhere seems dead now. No real activity online since 2014 as far as I can see, such as on User Voice. The VS2015 support is provided by a package with 2013 in the name. A friend and I tried it out recently but couldn't get it to work. It's a shame, but I see no indication that it works now or will in the future. @JesusSalas, please prove otherwise.

Comment: Hi @DrewNoakes, yes, you are right, VS Anywhere is officially down since 1 Apr 2016, unfortunately we were not able to make it happen and continue developing the product. I'm really sorry we were not able to make it for all you, we tried all what was reasonable but it was not enough, hopefully some day we'll have such feature provided by Microsoft or by another company that do better than us...

Comment: @JesusSalas, I'm sorry to hear that. Good luck for the future.

Comment: @JesusSalas, have you considered open sourcing your work? The community might be able to run with it.

Comment: @JesusSalas the idea of opening your code could both prove useful for the community and get you extra coin through donations

Comment: @PPC I'd love to, (for free, no extra coins required ;)), however we'll need to wait and see what happens...

Answer (score 3):

I can't say I've done this much (I helped someone with an Android program via a GoToMeeting session once!), but I would say any sort of screen sharing software would be your best bet. There are many options, but I would probably start with something like [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx), [Skype](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/features/allfeatures/screen-sharing/), or [join.me](http://www.join.me) and see if it fits the bill.

Comment: Please note that seeing the code is useless in pair programming if one can't also carry on a conversation with your partner.  In this respect Skype is probably the best of the mentioned tools, since it provides audio as well as screen sharing.

Comment: Let's not forget about using the telephone :)

Comment: I understand you are not aware of this tool but what he is asking for is VS Anywhere that is not the same to use TeamViewer, Skype or Join.Me as these are screen sharing tools and not a Real Collaborativelly Remote Distributed Pair Programming Platform for Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, had no idea this existed - no reason for a downvote though - especially when you aren't disclosing you are self promoting your own software

Comment: @Evan, as a rule, I use to downvote responses when they are not right or I think they do not provide a helpful tip at all. People do exactly the same with me. It seems you downvote things just because you don't like how people interact  with your answers, IMHO this is really a strange behaviour, let's do something, I'm going to include I'm the software Owner and see what you do next. Answer will not be more truth because this :).

Comment: @JesusSalas I downvote when I see a thinly veiled attempt at self promoting a product you created with 0 disclosure on a public community site. This seemed like a poorly hidden attempt to generate traffic for yourself, and I do not feel that adds merit to the discussion. If you disclose however, that is perfectly fine, as you are upfront about what you are doing. As such, I reverted my vote, as what your post says now is considered, by and large, the honest thing to do. Integrity is key ;-)

Comment: @Evan now, as you said, everything is in place. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

2018 update: [Visual Studio Live Share](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/live-share/) has been released. (And VSAnywhere extinguished)

Answer (score 0):

Will they be at the same computer as yourself? If so you could use two keyboards, or if not then try a remote access tool.

Beware that some will prevent simultaneous input from the host and the remote ends. [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/) is quite good at simultaneous local and remote input. [LogMeIn](http://www.logmein.com) is good too, but tends to block simultaneous input.